# Is it possible to do setup default ipython profile via enviorment variable

Tags: debian, ipython

I have a very customized profile file `profile_foo` that is used in project `foo`, however I'd like to keep this configuration separate from my `profile_default`. Is it possible to to conditionally enable default `ipython` profile via some environment variable, without having to pass: `ipython notebook --profile foo` every time I launch the notebook?

Ideally I'm looking for something that can be insetrted inside existing script that is sourced before working on the project.

I use debian linux.

Comment: I don't think there's an environment variable for profile, but you could point it to an entirely different IPython directory with the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable. You could also alias `ipython` to `ipython --profile foo` in your script.

Comment: I guess that ``IPYTHONDIR`` points to: ``.ipython`` not ``.ipythhon/profile_foo``.

Comment: This works as intended --- care to change your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer because it apparently helped:

I don't think there's an environment variable for profile, but you could point it to an entirely different IPython directory with the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable (this is instead of `~/.ipython`, not `~/.ipython/profile_foo`).

Alternatively, you could alias `ipython` to `ipython --profile foo` in your script.